# Real IP on traefik AWS ELB running on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, traefik, amazon-eks, traefik-ingress

I have deployed a service on EKS cluster(v1.13) configured with traefik(v1.7). I have whitelisted the source IPs and enabled Proxyprotocol on ELB as well. I am not able to get the client's real IP. Here is how I have configured.

traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints.https.whiteList]
  sourceRange = ["10.100.0.0/16"]
  useXForwardedFor = true
[entryPoints.https.proxyProtocol]
  trustedIPs = ["10.100.0.0/16"]
[entryPoints.https.forwardedHeaders]
  trustedIPs = ["10.100.0.0/16"]
```

Ingress object:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "test-dev"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-host: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-x-forwarded-for: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.100.0.0/16"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test-nginx.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx-headers
              servicePort: 80
```

Output:

```
$ curl https://test-nginx.example.com/
Hostname: nginx-headers-5f544s5cc3-sl5c6
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 10.100.0.57
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test-nginx.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 54.31.147.124, 10.100.0.57
X-Forwarded-Host: test-nginx.example.com
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Server: test-dev-traefik-7549d898bc-ttjf4
X-Real-Ip: 10.100.0.57
```

Am I missing something here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, have you ever solved this? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a secure solution but at least you will see the Real IP and can proceed with debug

```
[entryPoints.https.whiteList]
  sourceRange = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  useXForwardedFor = true
[entryPoints.https.proxyProtocol]
  trustedIPs = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
[entryPoints.https.forwardedHeaders]
  trustedIPs = ["0.0.0.0/0]
```

and annotation:

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

it works for me in Docker Swarm